# Kafka in the TensorFlow: Failed to consume:Broker: No more messages

Tags: tensorflow, apache-kafka

I want to use the kafka api in the tensorflow 1.7,however I got the error that Failed to consume:Broker: No more messages. I don't know how to fix this problem.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.kafka as kafka
temp =  kafka.KafkaDataset(topics='bt1_meeting_appeventlog_oracle:0:0:-1',group="None", 
                           servers="kafka1:9092,kafka2:9092,kafka3:9092")    
iterator = temp.make_one_shot_iterator()
#iterator = temp.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

then I got the error :

```
InternalError (see above for traceback): Failed to consume:Broker: No more messages
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext_13 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_4)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I meet the same problem when testing TensorFlow's Kafka client. In my case, setting eof tag of the KafkaDataset to True will solve this problem.

Tensorflow uses librdkafka as its c++ Kafka client. In librdkafka, EOF is treated as an error by default. By setting EOF to True will solve this problem.